# Fetching from SQL file using Core Data works only on a single simulator

Tags: ios, sql, swift, xcode, core-data

This is what I did:

1. Filled an SQL database using Core data and a parser from a CSV file.
2. This was only a one time fill. It will never be needed to repeat
   this.
3. Successfully fetched data from this SQL database using iPhone SE simulator.
4. Changed simulator to anything else than iPhone SE.
5. I am not able to get any data from the database. I always get zero results (empty arrays), as if there were no matching data in the database.
6. If I change the simulator back to iPhone SE, it works again.

I think it must be something with being able to connect to the SQL database. Here is the simplified fetchData func I am using:

```
func fetchData() -> [[Any]]{

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FullEntity")

let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()
//CoreDataStack class from a different file. It defines persistent container.

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

let context = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext

do{
    let results = try context.fetch(request)
    //results are transformed into array here
}catch{
    print("Some error")
}
return results
}
```

Comment: Each simulator is separate. There are no shared files or data between simulators.

Comment: If you have changed the simulator you need to fill the database again or you can reuse and copy (e.g. via Finder) a filled sqlite database to the other simulator's document directory. Learn here how you can find the path to core data files: [get-path-to-file-in-core-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801480/get-path-to-file-in-core-data)